# How to show windows user control from another windows user control?

Tags: .net, winforms

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the below scenario:

I have a windows form in which a windows user control(first user control) is present. On click of the button in the first windows user control I want to show another windows user control(second) and hide the first one.

Please let me know the procedure to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things here.

Create 2 controls at design time, `userControl1` and `userControl2`. Set the `Visible` property to true,false respectively. In the `OnClick`event for your button, set to false,true for Visible.

Create 1 control at design time. In the `OnClick` event, create a second control dynamically, and add it to the form, and hide the first one.

Which one you use, will depend on your exact situation.

Answer (score 1):

Declare & Raise an event from the first user control to the Windows Form. The windows form will then hide the first one and show the second user control

Or.

On click of first user controls button Hide the user control. the windows form can then listen for the visibilechange event and Show the second user control